# How to reopen window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

The following code should close the current file and open it again. Instead, it keeps opening only new windows.

Does anybody have a hint for keeping the old window closed?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import subprocess 

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def run(self, path):
        subprocess.call(['python',path])

    def initUI(self):
        self.close()
        self.btn_newSearch = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.btn_newSearch.clicked.connect(lambda:self.run('tests.py'))

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Python Script')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have put `self.close()` in the wrong place. Also, you should not use `subprocess.call`, as it will block until the command completes. It's better to use `QProcess` instead:

```
    def run(self, path):
        QtCore.QProcess.startDetached('python', [path])
        self.close()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn_newSearch = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        ...
```